# Can I move the old Ubuntu snap folder's content to new installed Ubuntu snap folder

Tags: directory

I have installed one Ubuntu 20.04 on my 18.04 Ubuntu, so I have seen in the home folder I have had the old user files, like download and ...files.
so I have moved my old Ubuntu profile files from `Documnets`, `Desktop`,' My Documents`,` Pictures`and`Videos`to the new profile folder, but I want to know can I move the content of old profile's`snap folder`to new profile folder's`snap folder`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can. When you first run a snap application after the folder is copied on the new system, the existing configuration, i.e., the folders you copied there, will be used.

Make sure you make the copy correctly. Permissions should be preserved, ownership as defined by the user id (UID) should be that of the user on the new system (if you are the only user, that will probably be the same user), and symbolic links should be preserved in the copy.